# OS 8.1 Mobile Safari Crashes when adding options to a <select> element

Tags: ipad, safari, ios8.1

I got the following crash report when trying to add options to a  element using jQuery 1.11 and native javascript. Any ideas? Does anyone know anything about this crash?

```
Date/Time: 2014-11-26 11:45:28.852 -0600
Launch Time: 2014-11-26 11:40:10.181 -0600
OS Version: iOS 8.1 (12B410)
Report Version: 105
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread: 0
```

Last Exception Backtrace:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x2bb3bc1a exceptionPreprocess + 122
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x39720c86 objc_exception_throw + 34
2 CoreFoundation 0x2bb3bb60 +[NSException raise:format:] + 108
3 UIKit 0x2f2023a2 -[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 442
4 UIKit 0x2f2021be -[UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 34
5 WebKit 0x2f979aaa -[WKSelectTableViewController viewWillAppear:] + 146
6 UIKit 0x2f010766 -[UIViewController setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 434
7 UIKit 0x2f2c6dc8 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke + 580
8 UIKit 0x2f074c48 _applyBlockToCFArrayCopiedToStack + 304
9 UIKit 0x2eff0aa6 _afterCACommitHandler + 454
10 CoreFoundation 0x2bb023b0 _CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION + 16
11 CoreFoundation 0x2baffa6e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 274
12 CoreFoundation 0x2baffe76 __CFRunLoopRun + 910
13 CoreFoundation 0x2ba4e20c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
14 CoreFoundation 0x2ba4e01e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
15 GraphicsServices 0x32e2d0a4 GSEventRunModal + 132
16 UIKit 0x2f05a1cc UIApplicationMain + 1436
17 MobileSafari 0x0007a944 0x72000 + 35140
18 libdyld.dylib 0x39ca0aaa tlv_initializer + 2
```

iPad, iOS 8.1

Comment: Of note, i experienced the same issues with iOS 8.1 and 8.2, but it appears to be corrected in 8.3.  It appears that iOS had an issue attempting the contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath method when rendering a UITableView for the select menu.  Perhaps Apple changed the point in which the control was instantiated or the method was called to ensure that there was data in the data source prior to calling contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath.  Just my speculation about the fix, but this issue is definitely the method call.